# Bounds on powers of sums

Tags: inequality

Given real numbers $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$ such that
$$\sum_{i=1}^n{x_i}^2 \leq \frac{1}{2},$$
find the greatest constant $c$ such that
$$\sum_{i=1}^n{x_i}^m\geq c^m$$
is always true for all odd $m \geq 2$.

I tried using bounds on absolute values, but I don't think the bounds I got are very sharp. Clearly $c\leq -\frac{1}{4}$ by considering $x_1 = x_2 = -\frac{1}{2}$. We also get $c=-1$ works, but it doesn't look sharp. Can anyone help?

Comment: Clearly an important case is where one of the x's is unequal to zero, and all the others are equal to zero. I suggest you examine this special case.

Comment: In this case, I get $c = -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$. How do I prove that this works for all choices of $x_1, \ldots, x_n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $m$ is odd, in case any $x_i$ is positive, we may replace it with $-x_i$ and get a tighter bound for $c$.  Hence we may assume $x_i = -\sqrt{a_i}$ where $a_i \geqslant 0$, and also we can see the constraint is an equality for optimum, as otherwise we may increase one of the $a_i$.  So it is enough instead to find the **maximum** of:
$$\sum_{i=0}^n a_i^{m/2} \qquad \text{given}\qquad \sum_{i=0}^n a_i = \tfrac12, \quad a_i \geqslant 0$$

For $m> 2$, the function $\sum a_i^{m/2}$ is convex and hence this can get maximized only on the corners of the convex domain - viz. when one $a_i = \frac12$ and all others are zero.  Accordingly, $c_{max} = -\frac1{\sqrt2}$.